# pyodbc exception args has some unidentified characters

Tags: python, oracle, exception, pyodbc

I am trying to log the pyodbc exception to a log file, the problem is, using the standard python logging, the code produces another exception related to encoding some unidentified characters (looks like Chines) that appears in the exception args, the exception stack trace:

> Exception:  [23000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00001: unique constraint
>   (REDWOOD.TITLE_PK) violated ORA-06512: at line 53  ઊȯ 诔唱  㸸ੌȯ   s ઉȯ 
>     㸸ੌȯ ꦓ倗翸 ᴘඇȯ 㫏杦翸 ɘઊȯ 텈ઉȯ 㸸ੌȯ 糆倘翸    !   H
>   촼杧翸  (1) (SQLExecDirectW)
>
> --- Logging error --- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "\Transfer\transfer\transfer_records.py", line 123, in transfer_record
>       row.PUBSTAT, row.CITED)   File "\Transfer\transfer\db_access.py", line 476, in transfer_record
>       self.cursor.execute(sql_block, params)
>
> pyodbc.IntegrityError: ('23000', '[23000]
>   [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00001: unique constraint (REDWOOD.TITLE_PK)
>   violated\nORA-06512: at line
>   53\n\x00ઊȯ\x00诔唱\x00\x00㸸ੌȯ\x00\x00\x00s\x00\uec40ઉȯ\x00\x00\uf600\x00\x00㸸ੌȯ\x00ꦓ倗翸\x00ᴘඇȯ\x00㫏杦翸\x00ɘઊȯ\x00텈ઉȯ\x00㸸ੌȯ\x00糆倘翸\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00!\x00\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00촼杧翸\x00
>   (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python\lib\logging__init__.py", line 994, in emit
>       stream.write(msg)   File "C:\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 167-168: character maps to  Call stack:   File
>   "/Transfer/trans_ui.py", line 162, in 
>       app.mainloop()   File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1277, in mainloop
>       self.tk.mainloop(n)   File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "/Transfer/trans_ui.py", line 130, in transfer_records
>       start_transfer.main(options=options, app=self)   File "\Transfer\start_transfer.py", line 19, in main
>       transfer.start()   File "Transfer\transfer\transfer_records.py", line 46, in start
>       list(map(self.transfer_record, self.transfer_rows))   File "Transfer\transfer\transfer_records.py", line 145, in transfer_record
>       logging.error("Exception details: " + ex.args[1]) Message: 'Exception details: [23000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00001: unique
>   constraint (THOTH.TITLE_PK) violated\nORA-06512: at line
>   53\n\x00ઊȯ\x00诔唱\x00\x00㸸ੌȯ\x00\x00\x00s\x00\uec40ઉȯ\x00\x00\uf600\x00\x00㸸ੌȯ\x00ꦓ倗翸\x00ᴘඇȯ\x00㫏杦翸\x00ɘઊȯ\x00텈ઉȯ\x00㸸ੌȯ\x00糆倘翸\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00!\x00\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00촼杧翸\x00
>   (1) (SQLExecDirectW)' Arguments: () Total Time:  24.116901397705078
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

The Exception handler that produces the exception:

```
        except pyodbc.Error as ex:
            print("Exception: ", ex.args[1])
            self.database.rollback()
            self.records_counter['transfer_errors'] += 1
            logging.error("Exception details: " + ex.args[1])
            self.status_update("An Exception Occurred while transferring 
            record: " + row.CTRLNO + "-" + row.LEVL + " Details:" + 
            ex.args[1], msgbox='Error')
```

What are these characters that appears as part of the exception args? 
How I can get rid of them as it seems they are producing the encoding exception

Comment: Perhaps `print("Exception: ", repr(ex.args[1]))` might give a clearer picture of what the message actually contains.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include the specific versions of Python and pyodbc you are using, along with the DRIVER= name of the Oracle ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of them by encoding explicitly so that you can use `errors="replace"` or `ignore`  The resulting bytes will not be pretty but they will be logged.

```
logging.error("Exception: " + str(ex.args[1].encode(encoding='charmap', errors='replace')))
```