# How to handle *any* pyodbc exception args encoding

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc

I was struggling with exceptions that were impossible to log like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781819/pyodbc-exception-args-has-some-unidentified-characters).

This approach with an explicit encode works

```
try:
    res = cur.execute(qry)
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    app.logger.error('database error! %s' % type(e))
    app.logger.error(str(e).encode(encoding='charmap', errors='replace'))
```

But the results can be rather ugly.
This is trying to search for '-' in a number column.

> ERROR in core: db_execute database error! <class 'pyodbc.DataError'>
> ERROR in core: b"('22018', '[22018] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722:
> invalid number\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00??\xee\x00\ue961??\x00??\xee\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x00\x00???\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?? (1722) (SQLExecDirectW)')"

I have not been able to determine what charset this really is.
I can tidy it up somewhat by picking apart `e.args`, but I have not been able to verify that args[0] and args[1] will always exist.

But the big issue is that I suspect args[1] can contain completely arbitrary strings form the database or driver.

I would be grateful for any clarification or hints about how to turn these exceptions into human readable and loggable strings, preferably independently of which DB we are using.

Comment: Do you get better results if you use [cx-Oracle](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/) instead of pyodbc?

Comment: cx-Oracle is not an option as I need to also support MSSQL and SQLite from the same codebase.